# Trouble setting up an asp.net core application as a systemd service on a virtual ubuntu machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, systemd

The result of

`$sudo systemctl status ascended.service`

```
WARNING: terminal is not fully functional
● ascended.service - Ascended Guild main site dotnet core application
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/ascended.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-04-09 04:11:55 UTC; 6s ago
  Process: 5743 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /home/ascended/ascended/src/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/linux-x64/AscendedGuild.dll (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)
 Main PID: 5743 (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)

Apr 09 04:11:55 aguild systemd[1]: ascended.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=200/CHDIR
Apr 09 04:11:55 aguild systemd[1]: ascended.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

/etc/systemd/system/ascended.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Ascended Guild main site dotnet core application

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/ascended/src/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /home/ascended/ascended/src/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/linux-x64/AscendedGuild.dll
Restart=always
RestartSec=30
SyslogIdentifier=ascended
User=ascended
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Executing `dotnet /bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/linux-x64/AscendedGuild.dll` from within the working directory as the user "ascended" runs the app normally.

From my research it seems the problem is the permissions on the working directory. I've tried changing the permissions but I am not very familiar with chown and the error has persisted.

Output of
`ls -la home/ascended/ascended/`

```
total 24
drwxrwsrwx  4 ascended www-data 4096 Mar 17 03:33 .
drwxr-xr-x 13 ascended ascended 4096 Apr  9 04:00 ..
drwxrwxr-x  8 ascended ascended 4096 Mar 17 03:33 .git
-rw-rw-r--  1 ascended ascended 6110 Mar 17 03:33 .gitignore
-rw-rw-r--  1 ascended ascended    0 Mar 17 03:33 README.md
drwxrwxr-x 12 ascended ascended 4096 Apr  9 03:38 src
```

Comment: Can you add the systemd service file to your post.